# SQLAlchemy: Pruning common database column prefixes

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I've got a database where each table has a common prefix for all the columns (probably to avoid aliases). Like this:

```
CREATE TABLE
    PERSON
    (
       PER_GUID RAW(16) DEFAULT SYS_GUID() NOT NULL,
       PER_FIRSTNAME NVARCHAR2(50),
       PER_LASTNAME NVARCHAR2(50),
       PRIMARY KEY (PER_GUID)
     )
```

Now when mapping this schema to the SQLAlchemy ORM (using `declarative_base`), I'd like to remove the prefix when mapping it to an object.

I could do it manually, of course:

```
class Person(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'person'

    guid = Column('per_guid', RAW, primary_key = True)
    firstname = Column('per_firstname', String)
    lastname = Column('per_lastname', String)
```

But that would circumvent some of the benefits of the declarative mapping, besides all the redundant typing. Basically I need the inverse of `__mapper_args__ = {'column_prefix': 'per_'}`, which prefixes my properties.

What's the proper idiomatic way of doing this? Do I have to capture some mapping events? Do something with a custom base class? The length of the prefixes varies, but they all end with an underscore, so something generic that doesn't need the exact table-prefix specified could work, too.

Answer (score 1):

If the column prefix is easily computed the pruning can be done using the column reflection event listener to change each column's `key` attribute to the desired value. This attribute is used to map ORM model columns to table columns.

Note that for this to work, the tables must be explicitly reflected - `Base.metadata.create_all` will not trigger the listener.

```py
import re
import sqlalchemy as sa
from sqlalchemy import orm

engine = sa.create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2:///test')


class Base(orm.DeclarativeBase):
    pass


@sa.event.listens_for(Base.metadata, "column_reflect")
def column_reflect(inspector, table, column_info):
    # Determine the prefix; here we assume all characters up to 
    # and including the first underscore in the column name.
    prefix = re.match(r'^([a-z]+_)', column_info['name'])[1]
    column_info["key"] = column_info["name"].removeprefix(prefix)


# Reflect tables of interest.
Base.metadata.reflect(engine, only=['person'])


class Person(Base):
    __table__ = Base.metadata.tables['person']


q = sa.select(Person)
print(q)
```

Output

```sql
SELECT person.per_raw, person.per_firstname, person.per_lastname 
FROM person
```

It's possible that the prefix is not easily computable, for example given a single column name `foo_bar_baz` the prefix could be `foo_` or `foo_bar_`. In this case the obvious solution would be to compare all the column names in the table to find the common prefix, but the column reflection listener does not initially have access to all the columns.  To get around this we can wait until the mapper is about to be instrumented, using the instrument_class listener instead of the column reflection listener.

```py
import os.path
...
@sa.event.listens_for(Base, 'instrument_class', propagate=True)
def receive_instrument_class(mapper, class_):
    table = class_.__table__
    column_names = [c.name for c in table.columns]
    prefix = os.path.commonprefix(column_names)
    for c in table.columns:
        c.key = c.name.removeprefix(prefix)
```

Note that this approach does not affect the table outside of the mapped class, whereas the column reflection approach affects the table however it is accessed. Regardless of the approach used, stringified foreign key references like `Column(Integer, ForeignKey('table.pk_col'))` must use the actual column name from the database.

Comment: The prefix is different for each table, not always `per_`. That's how the prefixes prevent column duplication in joins.

Comment: So the prefix needs to be a parameter, and you need a way to pass it from the class definition.

Comment: @Barmar Excellent point!  I've amended the answer to take this into account.